# SVG in cbz (comic)

Tags: evince, documentation, zip, svg

As an experiment, I create a CBZ (comic format) document that was composed of zipped SVG images rather the usual raster images

Evince happily opened this - much to my delight because it is a very convenient way to view a collection of SVG images (comic or not).

I can't find a specification for CBZ - I don't think one exists.

Is this Evince-specific behaviour, or can I create CBZ files from zip and SVG images and expect them to work with other comic readers?